# Can i continue studying architecture in Germany after i did two year of bachelor degree in architecture in Lebanon

Tags: graduate-admissions, university, germany, international-students

I started studying architecture in Lebanon and I have finished two years of bachelor degree and when I started the third and final year I decided to continue studying abroad,
So my question is: can I continue studying the third year or should I start from the beginning?
P.S.: I have a high school degree and the university I'm studying in is known internationally if this can help ! Thank you :)

Comment: Have you tried to discuss this with a German university?

Comment: Not yet, and of course I will :) but i saw this website and how much it’s helpful so i wanted to see if i get some information from here!

Answer (score 3):

The way this typically works in Germany is that you enroll at the new university for the desired degree. There will be requirements regarding what modules you need to pass for this degree. You can then apply for courses you have completed elsewhere to be considered as equivalent to some of those modules (this is called "Anrechnungsantrag"). The department will examine what topics were covered (which may require you to obtain translations of the syllabus etc), whether they consider the standards of the previous university sufficient, etc.

It is common that there are quantitative limits on how many modules you can do this for. Since you will ultimately get a degree from the new university, they'll want you to have done substantial studies with them. It seems far more plausible to me to get 1 year worth of modules acknowledged than 2 years.

Getting a definitive positive answer before enrolling is not likely, but if you haven't chosen the German university yet, getting in touch with the relevant
Prüfungsamt at your candidates for a pre-inquiry might give you some indication of how open to the prospect they are.

Comment: Ow thank youu ! this made things clearer for me and it’s so helpful for someone that don’t know what to expect :) thanks again