# Can I continue studying in Germany/sweden after a few semesters elsewhere?

Tags: career-path, university, germany, early-career, sweden

I am a second year architecture student at the University of Aleppo. I will start the third year soon. I decided to continue studying abroad, so my question is: can I continue my studies in Germany or Sweden or do I have start from the beginning? Will the courses I already took be counted towards my degree or not?

Comment: I edited to question to make it more general, otherwise it will probably closed due to depending on individual factors.

Comment: In Germany, this probably depends very much on the specific university you'd like to apply too. I'd recommend to google "[name of university] international office" and get in touch. [Here](https://studieren.de/architektur.hochschulliste.t-0.c-17.filter-13.html) you can find a list of German universities which offer a Bachelor's degree in architecture.

Comment: I would suggest talking a trusted advisor in your field about this. Moving countries is not easy, and fields like architecture may have licensing requirements that will make it difficult to use a Swedish/German degree unless you stay in Sweden/Germany long term.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can i continue studying architecture in Germany after i did two year of bachelor degree in architecture in Lebanon](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/167712/can-i-continue-studying-architecture-in-germany-after-i-did-two-year-of-bachelor)

Answer (score 5):

I will try to give a general answer for Germany:

In Germany, if you apply to a university you have to disclose previous study experience, the tests you took and passed/failed and any grades you have achieved. That is because you are not allowed to retake the same test more than three times (e.g. if you failed at linear algebra 3 times, you cannot study any subject that has this course as a requirement). If the studies were done abroad (as in your case) and the documents are not in german (english might be acceptable, too), you probably will have to provide a transcript.

Usually, the administration people evaluate your previous courses and see if any of them can be counted towards the subject you are planning to apply for. Depending on how much the curriculums overlap, you might be placed into a higher semester instead of the first. But this decision is made on a university level, one uni might agree to put you in third semester, while another says you have to start from the beginning or in the second semester.

Contact the universities that you would prefer to study at and inquire there.

Answer (score 4):

Do note that architecture is highly sought-after and each university has its own requirements for admission that may include portfolios or motivational letters or tests. You will also need German at level C1. And they may have different deadlines than other programs. (We have an international student trying to get into a Master's program staying with us in Germany, what a nightmare all the different rules are!)