# Continuing Vet School when moving to Germany

Tags: university, germany, veterinary-medicine

I want to move permanently from Romania to Germany and continue my studies along the way. I just finished my third year at the Veterinary School. My question is can I continue it here or do I need to start from 0 again.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From Romania, sorry I forgot to mention.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I continue studying in Germany/sweden after a few semesters elsewhere?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/186900/can-i-continue-studying-in-germany-sweden-after-a-few-semesters-elsewhere)

Comment: I would presume it is up to your target vet school in Germany if they would accept transfers, and how many of your credits they might take.